# SQL Statement to Return Results from Two Tables

Tags: sql, datatables, inner-join

I tried searching for this question but I don't think that I am wording it properly.

I have two tables, one for cases and one for hardware ordered, the hardware ordered table stores who placed the order, the date ordered, etc but I only want one column from this table which is Hardware Ordered, Yes or No.

The way my mind is thinking right now is that I will query the cases table for all the fields I want and then I want to add the one column from the hardware ordered table.

I tried an inner join but it is not returning anything.

```
SELECT Cases.CreatedBy
       , Cases.CreatedByEmail
       , Cases.CreatedByID
       , Cases.CaseID
       , HardwarePart.Ordered
FROM Cases 
INNER JOIN HardwarePart 
   ON Cases.RecID = HardwarePart.RecID
WHERE 
   Cases.CreatedDateTime BETWEEN '2019-01-01 00:00:00.000' AND '2019-03-13 23:59:59.999'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your problem is on the relation between the two tables `INNER JOIN HardwarePart ON Cases.RecID = HardwarePart.RecID`

is `Cases.RecID` a primary key in the table `Cases` and `HardwarePart.RecID` is the foreign key in `HardwarePart` which connects with `Cases`?

Comment: Nour, you are amazing

Comment: So, accept the answer,which means done. Good Luck